# Working of electric motor

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, batteries, current

I'm quite new to electrical engineering and stuff. I want to understand working of electric motor in terms of automotive field. Like the work of electric motor and how it gets converted into mechanical energy for working of an electric car/truck? Kindly help.

Comment: This is very broad. Have you tried searching Google for "how does an electric motor work?"

Comment: Too broad question and this information is readily available from many sources. Any decent library will have a book explaining this.

Comment: Yeah sorry. This is broad but I'm trying to understand working of electric motor from automotive point of view. Though it's not a big difference, I'm finding it little bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common types of [electric motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_motor), which are brushed and brushless. Both use the same principle to turn electricity into mechanical force. The electric current fed to the motor passes through the two or more coils inside the motor. These coils are usually tightly wrapped copper wire, made with the purpose of creating a magnetic field. As the current passes through the coils, it creates a magnetic field that attracts the magnets connected to the motor's shaft and causes the shaft and the magnets to spin. Now, the two types of DC motor mentioned earlier are "brushed" and "brushless". Brushed motors generally have two magnetic coils and run on a normal DC current. The brushless motor, however, is more complex because it contains three or more coils (but usually just three) and three [Hall Sensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_Effect_Sensor). These sensors use back EMF (electric noise generated by the motor) to determine the shaft's position in relation to the coils. This allows the motor to be driven and controlled stably by a motor controller.

I hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can understand little bit. In this case, which one is induction motor ("brushed" or "brushless") and which one is PSM?